# how to upload an image to Firebase storage from my cordova app

Tags: firebase, image, cordova, firebase-storage, cordova-plugins

i'm facing a probleme while trying to upload an image to firebase storage because after taking the picture using my cordova camera i only get the image URL , i can desplay  it in my page but when i try to upload it in firebase storage i only get a file with a small size (= 9B).

ps: i already have the camera , file pluggings and all the links to firebase storage

Any help is welcome! Thanks

```
      document.getElementById('camera').addEventListener('click', cameraApp);
                function cameraApp(){
                    //Camera Plugin onSuccess****************
                    function onSuccess(imageData){

                            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
                            image.src = imageData;
                            imgUri= imageData;
                                alert(imgUri);
                                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imgUri, function onSuccess(fileEntry) {
                                fileEntry.file(function(file) { 
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onloadend = function() {
                                        filename = "tesht.jpg";
                                    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/images/' + filename);
                                    var data = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + imgUri;
                                    alert(data);
                                    storageRef.putString(data, 'data_url').then(function (snapshot) {
                                        alert('Image is uploaded by base64 format...');
                                    });
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                                });
                            },
                            function onError(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                createNewFileEntry(imgUri);
                            });
                      
                    }
                    
                    //Camera Plugin onSuccess****************
                    function onFail(message) {
                        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
                    }
                    //Camera Plugin Options****************
                    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
                        quality:100,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum:true,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                        SourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
                        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                        cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.BACK,
                        targetWidth: 300,
                        targetHight:400
                    });
                    
                }
```